# Resolving paths (with absolute symlinks) against a base prefix

Tags: shell, directory, filenames, symlink

Consider we mount a foreign directory tree under some location and then `chroot` into it:

```
mount /dev/sdx1 /mnt
chroot /mnt
readlink /usr/bin/myapp    # Outputs: /usr/libexec/myapp/run
```

Is there any tool to resolve paths inside */mnt* prefix **before (without)** doing `chroot`? For example, if there is a */usr/bin/myapp* file in */mnt* which is a symbolic link pointing to absolute path */usr/libexec/myapp/run* (rather than more robust *../libexec/myapp/run*), then how can this be resolved to */mnt/usr/libexec/myapp/run* without chrooting?

The `realpath --relative-to=DIR --relative-base=DIR` looks promising, but actually serves another purpose. Using `--canonicalize-missing` may slightly help when only one symlink appears in the path, yet it returns a path relative to its base, which by itself is not valid in the host system.

Of course it is feasible to write a script what traverses each path level manually and resolves every one of them using `readlink`, but that seems overkill.